# Update nodes by a list of ids and values in one cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've got a list of id's and a list of values. I want to catch each node with the id and set a property by the value.
With just one Node that is super basic:

`MATCH (n) WHERE n.id='node1' SET n.name='value1'`

But i have a list of id's `['node1', 'node2', 'node3']` and same amount of values `['value1', 'value2', 'value3']` (For simplicity i used a pattern but values and id's vary a lot). My first approach was to use the query above and just call the database each time. But nowadays this isn't appropriate since i got thousand of id's which would result in thousand of requests.

I came up with this approach that I iterate over each entry in both lists and set the values. The first node from the node list has to get the first value from the value list and so on.

```
MATCH (n) WHERE n.id IN["node1", "node2"] 
WITH n, COLLECT(n) as nodeList, COLLECT(["value1","value2"]) as valueList 
UNWIND nodeList as nodes 
UNWIND valueList as values 
FOREACH (index IN RANGE(0, size(nodeList)) | SET nodes.name=values[index])
RETURN nodes, values
```

The problem with this query is that every node gets the same value (the last of the value list). The reason is in the last part `SET nodes.name=values[index]` I can't use the index on the left side `nodes[index].name` - doesn't work and the database throws error if i would do so. I tried to do it with the nodeList, node and n. Nothing worked out well. I'm not sure if this is the right way to achieve the goal maybe there is a more elegant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create pairs from the ids and values first, then use `UNWIND` and simple `MATCH .. SET` query:

```
// THe first line will likely come from parameters instead
WITH ['node1', 'node2', 'node3'] AS ids,['value1', 'value2', 'value3'] AS values 
WITH [i in range(0, size(ids)) | {id:ids[i], value:values[i]}] as pairs
UNWIND pairs AS pair
MATCH (n:Node) WHERE n.id = pair.id
SET n.value = pair.value
```

The line

```
WITH [i in range(0, size(ids)) | {id:ids[i], value:values[i]}] as pairs
```

combines two concepts - [list comprehensions](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/3.5/syntax/lists/#cypher-list-comprehension) and [maps](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/3.5/syntax/maps/). Using the list comprehension (with omitted WHERE clause) it converts list of indexes into a list of maps with id,value keys.

Comment: wow it works wonderfully! May you can be so kind as to explain the line in more detail to me since I don't quite get through?
```WITH [i in range(0, size(ids))  | {id:ids[i], value:values[i]}]```
The first part seems a bit like a "foreach" and behind the | seems like a creation of a temporary node is that correct?

Comment: Thank you for your explanation now i got it! :- )